# How to embed HTML page with javascript code in Beamer LaTeX?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, beamer

How to embed HTML page with javascript code (precisely D3 library with some hover over capabilities) in Beamer LaTeX?

Idea is to have a slide with HTML page embedded and during presentation I am able to hover over certain elements, i.e. it's not just a screenshot but I am able to have javascript features also.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that.

Comment: so the only way is to "make" a movie of what I want to show and embed it (after I made some google research on this, its the only solution coming up)?

Comment: Yes, or make your slides in HTML instead of LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to :

1. keep the HTML page with javascript as is,
2. convert the rest of your Beamer latex presentation to pdf, and the pdf in-turn to HTML
3. link the two together.

[pdf2htmlEX](http://pdf2htmlex.blogspot.in/) is a great tool for converting pdfs to html, retaining all the style and formatting. It seems to work well on slides created using Beamer.

Answer (score 0):

http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/ will get your goal accomplished. You will need to convert your LaTeX to javascript and run it all in a browser together in a javascript module.

```
var pdftex = new PDFTeX();
var latex_code = "" + 
  "\\documentclass{article}" + 
  "\\begin{document}" + 
  "\\LaTeX is great!" + 
  "$E = mc^2$" + 
  "\\end{document}"; 

pdftex.compile(latex_code) // now you have it in a javascript object.
```

This way it will end up being more portable as a mini-web app as opposed to just using Beamer LaTeX.

At this point you ca introduce a library like D3, Greensock,jQuery or a even a javascript powered canvas module.